# Selenium - Same window - 2nd iteration

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am looping a site to run every 15 minutes in selenium, but i want the 2nd and next iteration to run in same previous window instead of a new window.Can anybody help.

Comment: question is not clear , please provide some detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Try `.refresh()` after you have loaded the site once already then just do a refresh every 15 minutes. You can close the window and restart. Simple make a bot to do that. The other option would be to just open it up in a new tab by using `.sendKeys()` <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd>